# How To make one function works for all tables row?

Tags: jquery

[This is the table and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27lD3.jpg)

i write this for one row should i write the same for each row for every table or there are another away

```
var firstDiv = $('#res1 tbody tr:first-child td div:first-child');
var SecondDiv = $('#res1 tbody tr:first-child td div:nth-child(2)');
var ThirdDiv = $('#res1 tbody tr:first-child td div:last-child');
var lastP = $('#res1 tbody tr td:last-child');
var count = lastP.text(0);
var cash = $('#res1 tbody tr:first-child td:last-child:first');
firstDiv.click(function () {
    six = 6;
    cash.text(six + parseInt($('#res1 tbody tr td:last-child:first').text()));
});
SecondDiv.click(function () {
    cash.text(4 + parseInt($('#res1 tbody tr td:last-child:first').text()));
});
ThirdDiv.click(function () {
    cash.text(2 + parseInt($('#res1 tbody tr td:last-child:first').text()));
});

[<style>
.mr { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Zebra striping */
.mr > th { 
  background: darkcyan; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
.mr > td, table.mr > th { 
  padding: 8px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: center; 
}
.mr > tbody > tr > td > div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.mr > tbody > tr > td > div:first-child {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%
}
.mr tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%
}
.mr > tbody > tr > td > div:last-child {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%
}
</style>][1]
<table class="table table-bordered mr" id="res1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Goals</th>
            <th>Attack action</th>
            <th>Defensive action</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
            <th>Fair play</th>
            <th>Infraction</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id=""></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>                                                        
</table>
```

i have 3 tables like this is there are a way to make it like function instead of writing on for each row.
Note: it should add points to the total first one(red): 6 points, second One: 4 points, third One: 2 points

Comment: what does this do? `td:last-child:first`

Comment: well `$('#res1 tbody tr')` would get you all the rows. `$('#res1 tbody tr td)'` would get you all cells in all rows. Depending what you want to do, you can then apply something to all the selected elements at once, or perhaps you want to loop them and do something different each time - you didn't really explain your objective beyond wanting to work with more than one row. I think maybe you just need to get a bit better at using the right selectors and understanding that you can select more than one thing at once.

Comment: what i want to do it will be app to evaluate each player number every player will be evaluated individual with different points every div with color will give a certain points per click at the end it will add every points in the total column so i was wonder if how can i make a function can use in every player number instead of make it manual for every player number at the first column.
i hope my description is clear and thanks for you support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what are you triyng to achieve but , in every click , you have to use the `this` (current clicked element )  then search for td ( search parent first then go to last td ) in order to set score for each row .

see below snippet

```js
var lastP = $('#res1 tbody tr td:last-child');
var count = lastP.text(0); 

$('#res1 tbody tr td div').on("click",function(e){
  console.log();
  do_calculation(this);
  
});

function do_calculation(element){
  var tdIndex = $(element).parents("td").index();
  var scoreArray = $("#res1 thead").find('th:nth-child('+(tdIndex+1)+')').data("score");
  var score = scoreArray[$(element).index()];
  var $cash = $(element).parents("tr").find("td:last-child");
  $cash.text(score + parseInt($cash.text()));
}
```

```css
mr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Zebra striping */

.mr>th {
  background: darkcyan;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mr>td,
table.mr>th {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.mr>tbody>tr>td>div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.mr>tbody>tr>td>div:first-child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.mr tbody>tr>td>div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.mr>tbody>tr>td>div:last-child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: limegreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered mr" id="res1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th data-score="[6,4,2]">Goals</th>
      <th data-score="[3,2,1]">Attack action</th>
      <th data-score="[3,2,1]">Defensive action</th>
      <th data-score="[2,1]">Skills</th>
      <th data-score="[2,1]">Fair play</th>
      <th data-score="[-3,-2,-1]">Infraction</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id=""></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what i want to do it will be app to evaluate each player number every player will be evaluated individual with different points every div with color will give a certain points per click at the end it will add every points in the total column so i was wonder if how can i make a function can use in every player number instead of make it manual for every player number at the first column.
i hope my description is clear and thanks for you support.

Comment: I can't understand  this _i make a function can use in every player number instead of make it manual for every player number at the first column_

Comment: Thanks so much for you help.
Ok, what i mean it will be a different points so i want to change the value of the colored div per click . . . 
i will attach a pic to clear my point
http://prntscr.com/j9cvpq
i appreciated ^_^

Comment: @MrWebDev I've just simplified the code and also , in the thead th tag I ve added ana array of score of each th ( data-score attribute )
then onclick I get the value add it to final score

Comment: Great solution, this is exactly what i want . . . Thank you so much
but what if i want to make redo for last click ! what i mean if i want to remove the last click value point 
Thanks for your help .
really i appreciated

Comment: You're welcome @MrWebDev , I think asking new question would be better

Comment: @MrWebDev , adding just two varible that stores last score and lasst accessed td will do what you asked but it's not related to this question , you can create so new question for this